# What's the proper adjective to use with the phrase "bill details"? And what's the proper tense?

Tags: phrase-request, sentence-choice

I'm not sure what to use:

> The bill details or the break down of the bill will (**Appear - be ready - come out - or something else**) within the next week.

Also, How can I say that I don't have them now?

> 1. The bill details are not ready yet.
> 2. The bill details have not been ready yet.
> 3. The bill details was not ready yet. (I think this is wrong).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Bill* can be used to document the cost of any service or product, but in actual conversation we normally use *bill* for simple transactions.  At a restaurant you pay the *bill* after you finish eating, or you might get a *bill for services* when you bring your car in for an oil change.

For more complicated transactions, particularly in business, the more common term is *invoice*.

> [**invoice**](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/invoice) (n): A list of goods sent or services provided, with a statement of the sum due for these; a bill.

Example:

> We will prepare an **invoice** and send it to you as soon as it's ready.

This can sound more professional, especially in a business environment where the service is complicated enough to require listing the details.  By definition the *invoice* contains all the details of the transaction, so unless there is some contextual need, you shouldn't have to explicitly say it includes details.

Note that *invoice* can also be used as a verb, meaning "to send an invoice to someone".

> We will **invoice** you as soon as we [have/write up/put together/etc.] all the details.

Answer (score 1):

Bills or invoices contain items.

Items on an invoice or bill, in accounting parlance. One speaks of an itemized invoice or bill. That means a bill or invoice where you see the items individually that are being charged.

Generally speaking, we would say a bill or invoice is not ready. Not the items on it.

**Itemized bill or invoice** is the standard term. The word detail is not used here.

To itemize a bill or invoice.